# How different is Google App Engine in database structure

Tags: google-app-engine

i have a huge database about 300 mb , 14 tables work on internal network 
i think in deploying it on gae using web2py and postgres

1- generally is it a good idea ?

2- is it easy to alter the database structure to work on gae ?

3- what about the sql ?

4- is it easy to learn the gae way ?

```
                                                   thanks very much
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea - you can't use Postgres with GAE period.

1. It's a good idea if you want to rewrite everything and totally change the structure of your application, which if it's "just 'cause it's cool" sounds like a big waste of time.
2. No it is not going to be easy, for example, no JOINS period. There are many more reasons.
3. There is no SQL to begin with.
4. It's a relatively straightforward system and extremely powerful, but switching from postgres to their datastore is not going to be a simple process.